# How to use variable in url?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to develop a maco in python. I need a method that changes the URI given in the input variables.

For instance, in `www.(variable).com` I need to change the URL `www.1.com` to `www.2.com`

Comment: You can use [F-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#:~:text=Also%20called%20%E2%80%9Cformatted%20string%20literals%2C%E2%80%9D%20f-strings%20are%20string,runtime%20and%20then%20formatted%20using%20the%20__format__%20protocol.). They will replace the variable on the string. And also when opening any question in SO, follow this guide to provide a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *formatted strings* like this:

```
variable = 1
url = f"www.{variable}.com"
```

Comment: I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You could store your list of names in a list and then interpolate the variable into the f-string like:

```py
names = ['google', 'amazon', 'microsoft']
for name in names:
    print(f"www.{name}.com")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
www.google.com
www.amazon.com
www.microsoft.com
```

Comment: I really appreciate it